# How is a DataTable added to a DataSet in this example?

Tags: c#, sql

How is a new DataTable created in this code?  Is it the DataAdapters .Fill method that is creating it?

```
var da = new SqlDataAdapter(//Sql query, //DB connection);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();

da.Fill(ds, "TableName");
DataTable table = ds.Tables[0];
```

When I looked at the documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.fill(v=vs.110).aspx

There was no .Fill method that took the two parameters (DataSet, string) which has left me very confused as to how my code works.

Also if you have two different queries that both are accessing the same data, is there some conditional stopping a new table from being created?

For e.g. I had 3 queries in one class, the second two accessed the same data.  When I tried

```
ds.Table[2]
```

for the 3rd query, it threw an exception "table 2 not found".  But when I changed it to

```
ds.Table[1]
```

it worked fine.

Mostly just confused with how a new table is created and added to a dataset in this example and also why I can't find the method I used in the documentation.

Comment: You're looking at the documentation for the wrong class. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.fill(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using SqlDataAdapter class and this class contains a fill method that takes 2 parameters.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx

```
dataSet
Type: System.Data.DataSet
A DataSet to fill with records and, if necessary, schema.

srcTable
Type: System.String
The name of the source table to use for table mapping.
```